# Laravel abstract class auto injection

Tags: laravel-5, dependency-injection

Laravel auto injects abstract class , but when there is another parameter with abstract class, Laravel ignore it and hence, getting error.

```
public interface PostRepository {
public function getPostById($id)
}
class EloquentPost implements PostRepository{

public function getPostById($id){

return Post::find($id);
} }
```

Its working fine when I use it like:

```
class Controller PostController {
private $post;
public function __construct(PostRepository $post)
   $this->post = $post;
}
```

But when I use it like

```
class Controller PostController {
private $post;
public function __construct($someOtherParam, PostRepository $post)
   $this->post = $post;
}
```

then Laravel show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is unable to determine what should be injected as the first parameter to the controller's constructor as you have no type hint for that parameter.

If that `$someOtherParam` is something that should come in the URL, you will be able to have that injected in controller's action method to which given route points, but not in the constructor.